# Function calls in JetStrap

Tags: javascript, button, twitter-bootstrap, alert, jetstrap

I am trying to use the JetStrap editor to mock up some user interfaces before they are fine tuned and deployed. I'm very new to it, only been using it for a few days.

I put this javascript code in the HTML on a button:

```
<button onclick="alert("I am an alert box!");">
   Click Me
</button>
```

When I switch to "Test" mode and click the button, nothing happens.

Is the execution of script prohibited in the Jetstrap editor?

**Edit** - Adding in some new code for a comment:

HTML:

```
<button id="thisbutton">
    Click me!
</button>
```

Code:

```
$('#thisbutton').click(function() {
  alert('I am an alert box!');
});
```

That code snippet is the entirety of my "JS" tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using double quotes inside of double quotes, which is why it's not working.

I just tested in Jetstrap it with the single quotes and it's working:

```
<button onclick="alert('I am an alert box!');">
   Click Me
</button>
```

However, I would recommend adding an id to the button and then in the Javascript editor doing something like

```
$('#thisbutton').click(function() {
  alert('I am an alert box!');
});
```

Which is a better solution as you add more code.

Comment: Max, thanks for getting back so quick! The first suggestion you made worked like a champ. I'll edit my initial answer and add the code I put in to see if I'm messing something up. Can't get your second suggestion to work.

Comment: Ok now it is working! Perhaps I fat fingered something in... Thanks again!